# Cron job in Plesk

Tags: wordpress, cron, wget, plesk

In Plesk panel I get the log error : `wget command not found`. But there is already wget command installed.

How could I solve this issue ?

cron command: wget -q -O – http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should simple and straight forward. what you need to do is install

```
On Ubuntu:                  sudo apt-get install wget 
or on Fedora/Redhat/Centos: sudo yum install wget
```

make sure you have rights to run apt-get install or yum install. After you install wget that error in Plesk should go away. By the way, instead of wget -q -O you can also use cURL as an alternate solution to call your cron script.